# Search ios reminders without date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, eventkit

I'm familiar with using the `eventstore` search predicates like `predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting:Ending:Calendars:`

but I'm trying to figure out how I can search for any incomplete reminders **that don't have any due date set**.  I've tried `NSCompoundPredicate` but `eventstore` won't fetch a predicate that's not created with its own predicate creation methods.  Any ideas?

Edit: As per the documentation, passing nil for both start and end dates results in all reminders, not solely reminders without dueDates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You can try to filter all incomplete reminders to get only without due date:

```
[store fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate
                            completion:^(NSArray *reminders)
     {
         NSArray *myReminders = [reminders filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                                 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dueDateComponents = nil"]];
         NSLog(@"%@", myReminders);
     }];
```

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting%3aending%3acalendars%3a) for `predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting:ending:calendars:`:

> **Discussion**
>   Pass `nil` for startDate to find all reminders due before
>   endDate. Similarly, pass `nil` for both startDate and endDate to get all
>   incomplete reminders in the specified calendars.

Comment: Passing nil for both startDate and endDate results in all incomplete reminders, with or without dueDates. The question is about searching for only incomplete reminders without dueDates.

Comment: I was afraid that was the only way because I was previously passing the NSPredicate off to the next viewcontroller to go fetch the reminders, but now it looks like i'll have to implement it differently. Unless there's another way?

Comment: Another caveat to this method is that it seems to take a significant amount longer to perform. When the tableview loads without this, everything loads up quickly as expected. When using this filter, there's a considerable gap between the view loading and the cells appearing.